# error while booting: end kernel panic not syncing vfs unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0 0)

Tags: boot, grub2

**Problem**

When try to boot, sometimes it says `attempt to read or write outside of disk hd0`

then

```
end kernel panic not syncing vfs unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0 0)
```

**Tried**

Tried reinstalling entire OS (Ubuntu 16.04 and 16.10 both)

Tried 2 or 3 versions of Kernel (4.8.something , 4.9.7.something)

**Configuration**

On main SSD
Have a 2GB boot partition
Other / partition only.

Other OS on another HDD (Have one SSD(18GB) and one HDD(320GB))

single os on single disk

Sometimes system boots, sometimes don't (failure 2 out of 3 times).

the result of bootinfoscript is [here](http://pastebin.com/5qrj2qDw)

can it be some hardware defect?

Thanks for helping in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing entire SSD, used a different SSD, same problem :(

Finally, I tried another SATA port (got my SSD into a HDD-Caddy) (3Gbps port)
Now it's working fine.

Probable issue was BIOS compatibility or speed. The default port for hard drive is 6Gbps, so that might be issue, maybe.